# How to convert [String : Any] to [NSAttributedStringKey : Any]

Tags: swift, nsattributedstring, swift4

Dealing with some objC API, I receive an `NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *>` which translates to `[String : Any]` in Swift and which I was using for [NSAttributedString.addAttributes:range:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmutableattributedstring/1414304-addattributes).

However, this method signature has now changed with Xcode 9 and now requires an `[NSAttributedStringKey : Any]`.

```
let attr: [String : Any]? = OldPodModule.getMyAttributes()
// Cannot assign value of type '[String : Any]?' to type '[NSAttributedStringKey : Any]?'
let newAttr: [NSAttributedStringKey : Any]? = attr
if let newAttr = newAttr {
    myAttributedString.addAttributes(newAttr, range: range)
}
```

**How to convert a `[String : Any]` to a `[NSAttributedStringKey : Any]`?**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`NSAttributedStringKey` has [an initialiser that takes a `String`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstringkey/2895250-init), and you can use `Dictionary`'s [`init(uniqueKeysWithValues:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2894798-init) initialiser in order to build a dictionary from a sequence of key-value tuples where each key is unique (such as is the case here).

We just have to apply a transform to `attr` that converts each `String` key into an `NSAttributedStringKey` prior to calling `Dictionary`'s initialiser.

For example:

```
let attributes: [String : Any]? = // ...

let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "hello world")
let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedString.string.utf16.count)

if let attributes = attributes {
    let convertedAttributes = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues:
        attributes.lazy.map { (NSAttributedStringKey($0.key), $0.value) }
    )
    attributedString.addAttributes(convertedAttributes, range: range)
}
```

We're using `lazy` here to avoid the creation of an unnecessary intermediate array.

Comment: Thanks! To be exhaustive, I had to do the reverse operation as well (`[NSAttributedStringKey : Any]` to `[String : Any]`) and in that case it was `Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: attr.lazy.map { ($0.key.rawValue, $0.value) })`.

Comment: @Hamish Why `lazy`? Wouldn't `attr.map { /* ... */ }` do the same in this case?

Comment: @MatusalemMarques It would achieve the same result, but using `lazy` avoids the creation of an unnecessary intermediate array (the key-value pairs are instead just iterated over once and inserted into the new dictionary, with the given transformation applied).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the

```
`NSAttributedStringKey(rawValue: String)`
```

initializer. But, with this, it will create an object even if the attributed string won't be affected. For example,

```
`NSAttributedStringKey(rawValue: fakeAttribute)`
```

will still create a key for the dictionary. Also, this is only available in iOS 11 so use with caution for backward compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

While Hamish provided a perfect Swift answer, please note that in the end [I solved](https://github.com/laptobbe/TSMarkdownParser/commit/a16d931fb0459b0ea574fe4213809ef3c66f8d08) the problem at the Objective-C API level directly. It can be done also with a small Objective-C wrapper if you have no control on the source code.

We simply replace `NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *` with `NSDictionary<NSAttributedStringKey, id> *` and we add a `typedef` for compatibility with earlier versions of Xcode:

```
#ifndef NS_EXTENSIBLE_STRING_ENUM
// Compatibility with Xcode 7
#define NS_EXTENSIBLE_STRING_ENUM
#endif

// Testing Xcode version (https://stackoverflow.com/a/46927445/1033581)
#if __clang_major__ < 9
// Compatibility with Xcode 8-
typedef NSString * NSAttributedStringKey NS_EXTENSIBLE_STRING_ENUM;
#endif
```