# @available api check not works in Xcode 8

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode8

I am writing **objective-c** code in **Xcode 8.0**, for API availability I am using

```
 if (@available(iOS 11, *)) {
        // iOS 11 (or newer) ObjC code
 } else {
        // iOS 10 or older code
 }
```

Unfortunately compiler fires:

> unrecognised platform name iOS

Why?

Comment: iOS 11 support was added in Xcode **9**

Comment: @MartinR if i write `if (@available(iOS 9, *))`,8,7  gives me same.

Comment: @Amit, it does not matter if you check for versions below iOS 11. You need to have Xcode 9 to be able to make the `@available` check.

Comment: @RashwanL how can i apply multiple checks for diffrent  version of iOS ?

Comment: Just extend and add more conditions to your if-statement.

Comment: @RashwanL let me explain you more. Some api works with `iOS8`, some with`iOS9`, So how can i apply checks with **Xcode8** , does `@available` or something else to use ?

Comment: @Amit, you can´t make this checks with Xcode 8. The `@availability` syntax are **only** available in Xcode 9. Upgrade your Xcode to version 9 and you´ll be able to check for iOS 8, 9, 10, 11 etc. Checkout my answer below it describe this.

Comment: Strange `if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {` is working in **Xcode8**, **Swift**

Comment: @Amit Objective-C and Swift are different languages. The `@available` syntax was added to a new version of Objective-C which is available only through Xcode 9, as others have mentioned. It doesn't matter what OS version you're _targeting_ — what matters is the version of the compiler you're _compiling with_, which is what has changed between Xcode 8 and 9.

Comment: @ItaiFerber true! this is correct answer of my question.

Answer (score 5):

As I wrote at [How to check iOS version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339722/how-to-check-ios-version/44429397#44429397):

- `@available` was added in Xcode 9
- `#available` was added in Xcode 7

If you need to test availability for multiple versions of Xcode, you can detect Xcode 9 with `#ifdef __MAC_10_13` or, better, [`#if __clang_major__ >= 9`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19387043/1033581), as below:

```
#if __clang_major__ >= 9
    // Xcode 9+
    if (@available(macOS 10.10, iOS 8.0, watchOS 2.0, tvOS 9.0, *)) {
        // iOS 8+
    }
#else
    // Xcode 8-
    if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) > NSFoundationVersionNumber10_9_2) {
        // iOS 8+
    }
#endif
    else {
        // iOS 7-
    }
```

Real case example taken from: https://github.com/ZipArchive/ZipArchive/blob/master/SSZipArchive/SSZipArchive.m